# Android - Como a pasta gen é gerada?

Tags: android, app

Criei um programa que usa um projeto base para gerar outros projetos. Os aplicativos tem as mesmas funcionalidades, o que muda é o layout, as imagens, os nomes dos pacotes, etc. O problema é que quando gero um novo projeto, abro no eclipse e dou um 'clean' o pacote onde se encontra o arquivo R continua com o mesmo nome do projeto base, ao invés do nome do novo projeto, o que obviamente resulta em erro de compilação. Eu pensei que limpando o projeto o nome do pacote na pasta gen seria alterado para o mesmo nome do pacote na pasta src.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém saberia me dizer de onde as meta-informações são extraídas para a geração da pasta gen?

Comment: Breno, como está o seu arquivo `AndroidManifest`? Porque o apt usa o `packageName` na raiz desse arquivo para criar todo código autogerado nesse módulo.

Comment: Wakin, muito obrigado! Realmente tinha uma linha no AndroidManifest que eu estava esquecendo de alterar.

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar o pacote onde são criados as classes auto-geradas, é só alterar o `packageName` no AndroidManifest.